# Pyside unchecking checkbox in QTablewidget extremely slow

Tags: python, pyside6

I want to unselect all checkbox included in a QTablewidget. The table doesn't have so much rows (400) and every time the Unchecking command takes like 10 seconds to process. I am trying to understand why it takes so long, any idea would be highly appreciated.

```
def load_nets(self):
    all_nets_query = ast.literal_eval(requests.post(self.url + "/get_nets").text)
    power_nets_query = ast.literal_eval(requests.post(self.url + "/get_power_nets").text)
    if all_nets_query:
        row_ind = 0
        for net in all_nets_query:
            self.table_net_selection.insertRow(self.table_net_selection.rowCount())
            cb_import = QTableWidgetItem()
            cb_import.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)
            cb_port = QTableWidgetItem()
            cb_port.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)
            cb_power = QTableWidgetItem()
            cb_power.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)
            cb_floating = QTableWidgetItem()
            cb_floating.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)
            if net in power_nets_query:
                cb_power.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked)
            cb_import.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter)
            cb_port.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter)
            cb_power.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter)
            cb_floating.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter)
            self.table_net_selection.setItem(row_ind, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(net))
            self.table_net_selection.setItem(row_ind, 1, cb_import)
            self.table_net_selection.setItem(row_ind, 2, cb_port)
            self.table_net_selection.setItem(row_ind, 3, cb_power)
            self.table_net_selection.setItem(row_ind, 4, cb_floating)
            row_ind += 1

def unselect_all_nets(self):
    for row_ind in range(self.table_net_selection.rowCount()):
        item = self.table_net_selection.item(row_ind, 1)
        if item:
            if item.checkState().name == "Checked":
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked) # Takes 10 seconds !!
    for row_ind in range(self.table_component_selection.rowCount()):
        self.table_component_selection.setRowHidden(row_ind, True)
```

Comment: That's odd, but it seems unlikely that unchecking the state would cause such delay, so I suggest you to provide a [mre] so that we can check it on our own and exclude any other cause.